# Use of synthetic vs. natural sounds in modern large games

Tags: sound, sound-effects, workflow

Wondering generally how sounds are created for a large game such as Halo or Mario. Obviously 8-bit games probably used synthetic sounds (like regular Mario), and modern games have prerecorded voices in them. But I'm wondering sort of how much natural sounding *synthetic* sounds are used in a large game. In reading about documentaries and movies, a lot of the time they have microphones and go around in nature (or have a sound studio) and record "natural" sounds. Also, some of the iPhone sounds like the bell and whatnot sound like real sounds, though not sure if they were programmatically generated / synthetic.

More specifically, wondering what an example of a game is that uses synthetic sounds (that sound realistic) extensively. I would like to learn what is possible with synthetic sounds as opposed to natural sounds, to see how realistic they can be. Then from there I might be interested in looking into how those realistic synthetic sounds are made.

Comment: As you know, this varies widely. Some games/features use real recordings extensively (driving games and shooters in particular tend to be very exacting about capturing the sound of a particular engine or weapon - though even these usually go through extra processing to adapt to changing gameplay), other features might use sounds synthesized from a combination of real field recordings, foley, and analog or digital effects. There's no one answer we can give that covers all large modern games. Can you try editing the question to focus on a problem you're currently working on in your own game?

Comment: I changed it to be about an example of a game using synthetic sounds that sound realistic. Thank you.

Comment: We generally discourage "list games that do X" questions here, as they're broad and open ended, and don't tend to age well as new games come out. What problem are you really trying to solve here? Do you want to use synthetic sounds in your game? *Then ask about **your game***. Is there a particular kind of sound you want to make, and you're not sure how to create the realism you want? That's a focused, answerable question we could help you tackle, though you might find the [Sound Design StackExchange](https://sound.stackexchange.com/) might have a higher concentration of relevant expertise.